# Vector of Doubly Linked Lists of Doubly Linked List Pointers

Tags: c++, list, vector, data-structures

I have a vector that contains Doubly Linked Lists, (i.e std::vector< DoublyLinkedList >) and then each Doubly Linked List will contain a pointer to another Doubly Linked List in the vector.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

So let's say we have the following vector of Doubly Linked Lists, { {1,2,0} ,{0,2,1,5}, {2,1,0,4,5} ,{4,5,1,0}, {5,4} }.

Let's look at the first Doubly Linked List in the vector, {1,2,0}. What I want is for 1 to point to the list {1,2,0} and 2 to point to the list {2,1,0,4,5} and 0 to point to {0,2,1,5} and similarly for the other lists in the vector.

In addition to having this kind of structure I also need the pointers to point to the correct list if we permute the elements of the vector.

So, say, if in the above example I swap the first two lists in the vector, which gives:

{ {0,2,1,5},{1,2,0},{2,1,0,4,5},{4,5,1,0},{5,4} }

I would still like in the list {1,2,0} that 1 points to {1,2,0} and 2 points to {2,1,0,4,5} and 0 to {0,2,1,5}.

So I am able to implement every part up until this last part.

What I've been doing so far for this part is, before the permutation I can have all the 0's in each list point to &vector[1] and then after a permutation I would have to go through every element in each list to find 0 and point them to 0's new position, so they would point to say &vector[k].

The problem with this is I have to search each list for 0 but I do not want to do the search. So is there any way to implement this without having to do a search? (The code is in C++)

Comment: why do you need such complicated and un-officient data structure like that? it seems like your problem is XY one.

Comment: I was trying to implement a structure for vertices and neighbors of a polyhedron. So each head of list is a vertex and then the following pointers are the neighbors of that vertex.

Comment: Pointers to elements in a vector is tricky and probably not worth doing. Every time you add, remove or move stuff in the vector the pointers change. I recommend a re-think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the issue you described, the other problem with storing your structures directly in a vector is that certain operations on a vector invalidate some or all existing pointers to the vector. Namely removing from, or inserting elements into the vector.

Generally, in situations like these, it's better for the vector to store pointers to objects, rather than the objects themselves. In your example, a `std::vector< DoublyLinkedList *>` is going to work better. Your various instances of `DoubleLinkedList` can store pointers to each other, directly, and moving the pointers around in the vector won't have any effect on their validity.

Of course, this solution also has some other issues to work through, such as heap management, that will have to be sorted out. But that would be a different question.